# How do I extend the Load JSON example from vasturiano to include images as nodes

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, graph-theory

On vasturiano's page about his force-directed HTML5 graph is an example that uses images as nodes in a random graph. I want to extend the example and load my own graph from a JSON file.

In the first example I tried to insert my own images and had success.

→ https://github.com/vasturiano/force-graph/blob/master/example/img-nodes/index.html

Now I want to extend the following example and load my own graph from a JSON file.

→ https://github.com/vasturiano/force-graph/blob/master/example/load-json/index.html

With the second example, I had success creating and loading a JSON file, but had no success trying to load custom images and use them in the graph. More specifically, I don't know what to put in the nodeCanvasObject() function.

I add my code below:

```
//image array + append suffix with map
const imgs = ['100.jpg', '200.jpg', '210.jpg', '220.jpg', '230.jpg', '240.jpg', '250.jpg', '260.jpg', '300.jpg', '310.jpg', '320.jpg', '330.jpg', '340.jpg', '350.jpg', '360.jpg', '370.jpg', '380.jpg', '400.jpg', '410.jpg', '420.jpg', '430.jpg', '440.jpg', '450.jpg', '460.jpg', '470.jpg']
      .map(src => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = `./gewebe/${src}`;
        return img;
      });

//JSON Graph
fetch('assets/js/neuetendenzen.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
         const Graph = ForceGraph()
              (document.getElementById('graph'))
                //graph data structure and incremental updates
                .graphData(data)
                //unique node id
                .nodeId('id')
                //node numeric value, affects circle area
                .nodeVal('val')
                //attribute for name shown in label
                .nodeLabel('name')
                //attribute referring to id of source node
                .linkSource('source')
                //attribute referring to id of target node
                .linkTarget('target')
                //add image as node
                .nodeCanvasObject((node, ctx) => {
                    const label = node.id;
                    const bild = new Image();
                    bild.src = "./gewebe/100.jpg";
                    ctx.drawImage(bild, 20, 20, 20, 20);
                })
    });
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.